# Unable to cast object of type class to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#

Class 1

```
public class KlasaBetonaaaa
     {
         public string Naziv { get; set; }
         public double _Fck { get; set; }
     }
```

Class 2

```
 public static class Database
     {
         public static KlasaBetonaaaa[] GetAllKlasaBetona()
         {
             return new KlasaBetonaaaa[]
             {
                 new KlasaBetonaaaa
                 {
                     Naziv = "C12/15",
                     _Fck = 12.0
                 };
             }
         }
     }
```

Class 3

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            {

            var klaseBetona = Database.GetAllKlasaBetona();

            klasaBetonaComboBox.Items.AddRange(klaseBetona);

            }


private void klasaBetona_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedBeton = klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem;
            CalculateSomething((string)selectedBeton);
        }


        private void CalculateSomething(string selectedBeton)
        {
            fck.Text = selectedBeton;
        }
    }
```

This string selectedBeton is what i tried before with only 1 name converting to string from collection.
Now i created new classes (Manual database)as and array and i dont know how to link it so when i pick "C12/15" to get _Fck value 15.0 in a label.

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: I think the problem is that `selectedBeton` at the line `var selectedBeton = klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem;` is not a string, but a `KlasaBetonaaaa`. However, please provide more information about the error you are getting.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication3.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsFormsApplication3.KlasaBetonaaaa' to type 'System.String'.

This is what i wanna do here: When i pick Naziv in combobox that i cant get and link _Fck with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast to the actual type and then show the string of `_Fck`, you could always override the `ToString` method of your class and show that instead. Alternatively, if you do calculations on the object then you can pass that into the method instead.

```
var selectedBeton = klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem as KlasaBetonaaaa;
if(selectedBeton != null)
    CalculateSomething(selectedBeton._Fck.ToString());
```

Comment: one more question i got...
why now i get error here:
var _dFck = Convert.ToDouble(fck.Text);

Comment: Because the value in there doesn't comply to your current regional settings format for decimal separated decimals. @antestipe

Comment: when i put textbox instead of label then it works. How can i set it up so the value can not be changed?

Comment: @antestipe: Set `ReadOnly` to `true`.

Comment: @antestipe - Are you converting back to a double in this same method? if you are then you would be much better to just pass a double into your method and then call `ToString` when setting the text. Thank you for the replies, Patrick

Comment: @antestipe: Search SO for similar problems. If that didn't work out: ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

`klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem` is of type `KlasaBetonaaaa`, since you add an array of that type (`klasaBetonaComboBox.Items.AddRange(klaseBetona);`). That means that casting `SelectedItem` to `string` will fail.

You should cast the selected item to `KlasaBetonaaaa` and cast the `Fck` property, which is a `double`, using `ToString` (or if you want to take the `Naziv` string property, you don't need `ToString()`, since it is one already):

```
KlasaBetonaaaaselectedBeton = klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem;
CalculateSomething(selectedBeton.Fck.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have used an `IEnumerable<KlasaBetona>` as datasource for the combobox. Now you're trying to cast the `SelectedItem` which is a single instance of `KlaseBetona` to `string`. That doesn't work since you haven't [overloaded the `explicit`-conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) like this:

```
public static explicit operator string(KlasaBetona kl)  
{
    return kl._Fck.ToString();
}
```

But instead of that i suggest to cast the `SelectedItem` to `KlasaBetona` and use that property in the first place:

```
KlasaBetona kl = (KlasaBetona) selectedBeton;
CalculateSomething(kl._Fck.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got similar message `Unable to cast object of type class to type Enum` when I use JsonConverter to Serialize class.

Finally I found that I forgot to remove attribute `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]` on my string property, after remove the attribute, the problem is solved.